# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'restaurantId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im new to stack overflow.I started to create an MVC application and instead of using a Map.Route I use a binding attribute to pass in the id. Below shows the error and the code for each class/components.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'restaurantId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in
>   'OdeToFood.Controllers.ResturantReviewsController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter.

Model

```
public class ResturantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int ResturantId { get; set; }

}

Controller
public class ResturantReviewsController : Controller
    {
        private OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();

        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")] int restaurantId)
        {
            var restaurant = _db.Resturants.Find(restaurantId);
            if (restaurant != null)
            {
                return View(restaurant);
            }
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(int restaurantId)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ResturantReview review)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Reviews.Add(review);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = review.ResturantId });
            }
            return View(review);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

View

```
@model OdeToFood.Models.Resturant

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.Partial("View", Model.Reviews)
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { restaurantId = Model.Id })
</p>
```

Comment: Can you please provide url where it fails?

Comment: You parameter is named `restaurantId` (not `id`) so its `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { restaurantId = review.ResturantId });` and remove the `[Bind(Prefix = "id")]`

Answer (score 2):

From what is see you have action

```
 public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")] int restaurantId)
```

Remove Bind attribute

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
```

Bind prefix means that you POST/Get parameter as id.restaurantId. And you want to catch default routing which will read id from url like ResturantReviews/Index/2

Comment: Hi yes that did do the trick but I am now getting an error it is :The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ResturantReviews_dbo.Resturants_Resturant_Id". The conflict occurred in database "OdeToFoodDb", table "dbo.Resturants", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Within my restaurantreview model class do I need to add [Key] on ResturantId

Comment: Sorry Volodymyr here is the Url on the create review page I am now getting the right Id: http://localhost:52918/Reviews/Create?restaurantId=7

Comment: About url you have two ways 1. rename restaurantID to just id, second write custom Route for this but i would use just ID

Comment: About insert its not a key its foreign key which fails, make sure that in dbo.Resturants you have restaurant with this id which you try to insert review