# Where is my null entry for parameter error coming from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-parameters

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'restaurantId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in
>   'OdeToFood.Controllers.ResturantReviewsController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter.

**The error only occurs when I click the back to list button**

I am getting the same error as the [patron posting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688235/the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-restaurantid-of). I have tried out all of the suggestions on that post but I am able to add some additional points of reference not listed on that question. I noticed that when I hover on the 'back to list' link the url on the bottom of the screen does not contain the `restaurantId` which got me questioning as to why/how it works on the Pluralsight tutorial anyway.

[image]

I have even gone so far as replacing all of my files with those from the provided exercise files and I get the same error.

Here is the code that I believe is causing the error:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(RestaurantReview review)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(review).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = review.RestaurantId   });
        }
        return View(review);
    }
```

Comment: 1) Add your error to your question here. 2) Include the steps that lead you to the error. 3) Include your code for this view and the controller code that supports it.

Comment: @Jasen I have done as you requested

Comment: You need to show the relevant code - the view code for the 'Back' link and the signature of the `Index()` method (you also appear to have a problem with the `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = review.RestaurantId   });` line of code also)

Answer (score 0):

For the code that you posted (it helps but not much, should have posted the view's code and the create/edit/reviews actions code) my assumption is below:

What is happening is that you have an action that expected to receive an restaurantId (of type int, that means, not nullable) but it is not receiving any value for restaurantId, causing that exception. Probably, for what you say and looking at the code, it is the Reviews action that expects a restaurantId that it is not being provided. If the Reviews action has an restaurantId as parameter you should create the "Back Link" with that id.

Hope I´ve helped.

Regards,